# move files from one directory to another directory with awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a directory containing more than 1000 folders. Each folder of this directory contain one text file.I would like to move the text files from these folders to another  directory. But the name of the text file in the new directory should be the name of the folder from which it was extracted.

How can I do this with awk or bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for i in <folderlist>; do
    mv $i/*.txt <newfolder>/`basename $i`.txt
done
```

If all the folders are at the root, use `for i in *` or `for i in $(find <root> -type d -maxdepth 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(find  . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f ); do 
    mv  $i $YOUR_DIR/$(dirname $i); 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
find ./*/ -name "*.txt" | nawk -v new_dir="new_dir" -F/ 'NF==3{cmd="mv ""\""$0"\" " new_dir"/"$2;system(cmd);}'
```